# Find whether given conditions based records are matching or not in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and want to find out whether the given condition matches or not with existing table records. I tried with not exists but that doesn't work. What expression would fill the `is_exists` column like in the expected output below?

```
create table user1(id number, name varchar2(20), age number);

insert into user1 values(1, 'user1',   1);
insert into user1 values(1, 'user11', 11);
insert into user1 values(2, 'user2',   2);
insert into user1 values(2, 'user22', 22);
insert into user1 values(3, 'user3',   3);
insert into user1 values(4, 'user4',   4);

select id, age, is_exists
from user1
where id = 1 and age in (1, 11, 111);
```

Expected result:

```
id age is_exists
-- --- ---------
 1   1 true
 1  11 true
 1 111 false
```

Comment: What's the logic for choosing id 1 for the age 111?

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of table for the three set of values; which you can build using `select ... union all`. Then use `left join` or `exists`:

```
with cte as (
    select 1 as id, 1 as age from dual union all
    select 1,       11       from dual union all 
    select 1,       111      from dual
)
select cte.*, case when exists (
    select 1
    from user1
    where user1.id = cte.id and user1.age = cte.age
) then 'yes' else 'no' end is_exists
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL is designed to return a subset or transformed set of data from the underlying database. For example, `FROM` specifies that you want all columns and rows from a particular table. The expression list in the `SELECT` statement narrows down the number of columns you need from this table. The `WHERE` statement narrows down the number of rows you receive.

Every row in the result set is based on one or more existing rows in the original data set. In either case the maximum result is always the data that exists in the table.

Because you want one row for the age in the result set, you need one row for the age in the query source. If you don't have a table, creating a temporary one with a series of `UNION` is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the  same as 'Salman A', but using LEFT JOIN whose result is CASE tested in Select clause. Basicaly, if there is not a join then there is not a matching record...

```
WITH 
    fltr AS 
        (
            Select 1 "ID", 1 "AGE" From DUAL UNION 
            Select 1 "ID", 11 "AGE" From DUAL UNION 
            Select 1 "ID", 111 "AGE" From DUAL
        )
SELECT
    f.ID "ID", f.AGE "AGE",
    CASE WHEN u.ID Is Not Null THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END  "IS_EXISTS"
FROM 
    fltr f
LEFT JOIN
    USER1 u ON(u.ID = f.ID And u.AGE = f.AGE)
--
-- Result
--
--         ID        AGE IS_EXISTS
--          1          1 YES
--          1         11 YES
--          1        111 NO
```

Comment: Can do away with `1 as ID` too, if you put it in the SELECT and the ON

Comment: That's right, this is just a simulaton of sample data from the question, I expect that Christoph has some real data to replace the fltr cte and with some conditions that he needs. This was just an example of Left Join mentioned in Salman's answer. Regards...